# How to use Jersey as Rest client to connect Ambari for Authorization

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I tried to use Jersey to make a rest client to connect Ambari server. However, the authorization cannot be finished using the Filter.

Is there any other way for authorization in addition to the Filter?

The case I tries is as follows:

ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();

```
        clientConfig.getFeatures().put(
                JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);

        Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);

        client.addFilter(new ClientFilter() {
            private ArrayList<Object> cookies;

            @Override
            public ClientResponse handle(ClientRequest request) throws ClientHandlerException {
                if (cookies != null) {
                    request.getHeaders().put("Cookie", cookies);
                }
                ClientResponse response = getNext().handle(request);
                // copy cookies
                if (response.getCookies() != null) {
                    if (cookies == null) {
                        cookies = new ArrayList<Object>();
                    }
                    // A simple addAll just for illustration (should probably check for duplicates and expired cookies)
                    cookies.addAll(response.getCookies());
                }
                return response;
            }
        });

        String username = "admin";
        String password = "admin";

        WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://master.node.ibm.com:8080/api/v1/clusters");

        Form form = new Form();
        form.putSingle("Username", username);
        form.putSingle("Password", password);
        webResource.type("application/json").post(form);

        ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").type("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to post a form with the credentials - that is not what you want. For a standard basic authentication (same as done with `curl -u username:password`) you should

```
webResource.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(username, password));
```